# Tracing requests like Morgan does in NextJS using middlewares

Tags: node.js, logging, next.js, server, middleware

I want to trace requests, and their result (and codes), like [Morgan Logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) does, as if it were an express/koa middleware.

However, using `middleware.ts` file has some serious issues, being the top most that **I can't seem to find a way to "await" the response to complete by itself** (Thus, watch how the request was handled by the routers).

Also other problems arise from the fact that is using *edge* runtime, such as: No colors on terminal, no NodeJS native modules...

### Edit

I should point out that for the logger, all responses seem OK for that reason.